# Can I re-enter the US with an F1 Visa after arriving with a VWP (ESTA)?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, mexico, f1-visas

So currently I’m planning to enter the US with an ESTA on the 21st of December as my F1 Visa only allows me to enter on the 22nd of December. However, I’m unable to change my flight because I booked it with a promotional fare. What I’m planning to do is go to Mexico on the 27th of December for a night and then come back in the next day with my F1 Visa. Is that possible? From what I’ve heard so far it should be ok but I just wanted to ask around.

Comment: I don't see any issue with entering on VWP then exiting and re-entering with the Visa.  What I don't know, however, is whether you'd get an ESTA if you have a Visa (I don't know if they issue ESTA to passports with a Visa).